# How to implement search functionality in laravel with multiple input fields in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a online ticketing service using laravel and vue.js. I  want to implement search functionality in my website with multiple fields. eg: flight destination, arrival, date. I dont know how to implement it in laravel. I've watch several videos but it doesnt work for me. Can someone know what should i do?

Heres my output
[image]

index.blade.php

```
         <h2 class="text-4 mb-3">Book Domestic and International Flights</h2>
                <form id="bookingFlight" action="{{url("/flightSearch")}}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flightFrom" required placeholder="From">
                        <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flightTo" required placeholder="To">
                        <span class="icon-inside"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <input id="flightDepart" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Depart Date">
                        <span class="icon-inside"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-3 form-group">
                        <input id="flightReturn" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Return Date">
                        <span class="icon-inside"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span> </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>
```

FlightsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Flights;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FlightsController extends Controller
{
    public function searchFlights(Request $request){
       return $request->all();
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/flightSearch', 'FlightsController@searchFlights')->name('flightSearch');
```

Flights.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flights extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'flightFrom', 'flightTo', 'flightDepart', 'flightReturn',
    ];
}
```

Comment: please, add to the question the fields names of you Flights Model

Comment: like this sir  
`protected $fillable = [
        'flightFrom', 'flightTo', 'flightDepart', 'flightReturn',
    ];
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to add the method to the form and names to the inputs

```
<form method="GET" id="bookingFlight" action="{{url("/flightSearch")}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="flightFrom" class="form-control" id="flightFrom" required placeholder="From">
    <input type="text" name="flightTo" class="form-control" id="flightTo" required placeholder="To">
    <input name="flightDepart" id="flightDepart" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Depart Date">
    <input name="flightReturn" id="flightReturn" type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Return Date">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

and then you can perform the query based on the request data:

```php
public function searchFlights(Request $request){
    return Flights::where('flightFrom', 'like', '%' . $request->flightFrom . '%')
        ->where('flightTo', 'like', '%' . $request->flightTo . '%')
        ->where('flightDepart', 'like', '%' . $request->flightDepart . '%')
        ->where('flightReturn', 'like', '%' . $request->flightReturn . '%')
        ->get();
}
```

---

based on @RioHilmy comment, note you can use inputs type date for flightDepart and flightReturn:

```
<form method="GET" id="bookingFlight" action="{{url("/flightSearch")}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="flightFrom" id="flightFrom" required placeholder="From">
    <input type="text" name="flightTo" id="flightTo" required placeholder="To">
    <input name="flightDepart" type="date" id="flightDepart" required>
    <input name="flightReturn" type="date" id="flightReturn" required>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

then you can perform the query with the dates values:

```php
public function searchFlights(Request $request){
    return Flights::where('flightFrom', 'like', '%' . $request->flightFrom . '%')
        ->where('flightTo', 'like', '%' . $request->flightTo . '%')
        ->whereDate('flightDepart', $request->flightDepart)
        ->whereDate('flightReturn', $request->flightReturn)
        ->get();
}
```

Comment: use `whereDate()` for `flightDepart` and `flightReturn`

Comment: @RioHilmy yes, I guess it would be better, I wrote it like this because the OP uses inputs type text

Comment: When i use `whereDate` it returns me an empty array even if the data is right. And when i use `where` it gets all the data even i put wrong inputs.

Comment: I changed my input type to `date` in my arrival and departure input fields

Comment: try adding this line to the Flights Model `protected $dates = ['flightDepart', 'flightReturn'];`. There may also be a difference between the format of the date that is sent from the form and the format of the date of the DB. Could you confirm which formats you are using?

Comment: when i look at the search query in the url sir, the date format is like this `flightDepart=2019-08-30&flightReturn=2019-08-31` and when in my form the date shown is like this `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: also the date in my database is in `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: I fixed it sir. Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: great! glad to help